# Помогите понять разницу между getView и bindView?

Tags: android

Помогите понять разницу между двумя методами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getView()` вызывает 2 метода `newView` и `bindView` - грубо говоря это работает так:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //blah-blah
    View v;
    if (convertView == null)
        v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
    else 
        v = convertView;
    bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
    return v;
}
```

`bindView` просто связывает данные с адаптера/курсора с конкретной вьюшкой, которая если отсутствует создается в `newView`, а если имеется то берется из кэша

Comment: Спасибо теперь понятно

Comment: @Eser в этом форуме благодарность принято выражать по другому.